# error while loading shared libraries: libipmidetect.so.0

Tags: linux, error-handling

I have installed freeipmi-1.6.1 on my linux machine (ubuntu) which is runniz zabbix server.

I downloaded the freeipmi-1.6.1.tar.gz file from the freeipmi website and unzipped it, then i entered the extracted folder and typed in:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64`

then typed make and then make install.

now when i test the program it gives me an error message:

```
ipmi-sensors: error while loading shared libraries: libipmidetect.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
--libdir=/usr/lib64
```

There is no `/usr/lib64/` in Ubuntu. Which also means no /usr/lib64/ in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Ubuntu : There is `/usr/lib/x86_64/-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/`

---

The configure line for Ubuntu should be e.g.

`./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64/-linux-gnu/ --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man`

Comment: Thank You for Your answer.
what should i do now to fix the issue? 
i want to install freeipmi successfully.

Comment: Please install with a ./configure like my previous comment.